# C# lambda as parameter to method

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, delegates

In C# is it possible to have a method accepting a delegate that has zero, 1 or many parameters?

In the method below i want to be able to do al kind of things when i click yes on the dialog box. I used a delegate for this but currently it only accepts methods without parameters.

There are probably multiple ways to do this like passing a generic class containing the parameters but what is the best way to do this? Does C# provide something out of the box to do this in a elegant way?

```
    public static bool ShowCustomDialog(string message, 
                                        string caption, 
                                        MessageBoxButtons buttons,
                                        XafApplication application, 
                                        Action onYes = null)
    {
        Messaging messageBox = new Messaging(application);
        var dialogResult = messageBox.GetUserChoice(message, caption, buttons);
        switch (dialogResult)
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                onYes?.Invoke();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to create a method that accespts a func of any arbitrary number of parameters such as `Action<T>`, `ActionT1, T2, ...>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your question directly, that's why you use lambdas:

```
ShowCustomDialog("Hi!", "Greeting", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                 () => DoSomething(myArgument, anotherArgument));
```

This is at the core of techniques like dependency injection - the `ShowCustomDialog` method shouldn't know anything about the action *except* for the fact that it's something that doesn't require input *from the* `ShowCustomDialog` *method itself*. If `ShowCustomDialog` had to pass some argument, you'd use `Action<SomeType>` instead of `Action`.

Under the covers, the compiler creates a class that contains the arguments to be passed, and creates a delegate that `Target`s an instance of that class. So it's (mostly) equivalent to manually writing something like this:

```
class HelperForTwoArguments
{
  bool arg1;
  string arg2;

  public HelperForTwoArguments(bool arg1, string arg2)
  {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
  }

  public void Invoke()
  {
    DoSomething(arg1, arg2);
  }
}

// ...

ShowCustomDialog("Hi!", "Greeting", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                 new HelperForTwoArguments(myArgument, anotherArgument).Invoke);
```

This capability has been in the .NET framework since the very beginning, it just got much easier to use with anonymous delegates and especially lambdas.

However, I have to say I don't see any point to your "helper" method at all. How is it different from doing something like this?

```
if (ShowCustomDialog("Hi!", "Greeting", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
  DoSomething(myArgument, anotherArgument);
```

Comment: I guess OP needs to pass any arbitrary method with any arbitrary number of parameters, not only one. So Also this should work for him: `(x) => x.DoSomething(myArgument, anotherArgument));`

Comment: @HimBromBeere Which you wrap in a delegate that has zero arguments - exactly what I suggested in the first place. Either the method must *know* about the arguments, and then there's no point in allowing delegates that don't fit the signature, or it doesn't care about the arguments, and then it just takes `Action`.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for now i can pass methods to ShowCustomDialog and it doesnt have to know anything about what kind of method it is.